# How do I repackaged an AAR for Android gradle manifest merger?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, aar

There is a huge problem with Samsung 4.2.2 devices using android.support.v7.appcompat v21:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377

To avoid this problem, I figured that I would take the v21 appcompat aar from the .m2repository and:

1. Unzip appcompat-v7-21.0.0.aar
2. Use jarjar to process the classes.jar with rule (rule android.support.** android.support.@1)
3. Replace the classes.jar with the repackaged classes.jar
4. Zip appcompat-v7.21.0.0.aar
5. Include the repackaged aar manually in my build.gradle (compile(name:'appcompat-v7-21.0.0', ext:'aar') with a flatDir of my libs folder in build.gradle repositories section).

The problem is when I compile with the repackaged aar, I get an FileNotFoundException from the manifest merger. So, I'm trying to determine if what I'm doing is even possible and to what my error is if it is possible.

Here is the error I get:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/appcompat-v7-21.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

EDIT:

When I look at in the path app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/appcompat-v7-21.0.0/ the AndroidManifest.xml is definitely present.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? having the same issue myself now

Comment: @glogic I just ended up using proguard, which seems to be the standard way to solve the main problem with the samsung 4.2.2 devices.